# Find out whether string has date in it

Tags: php

I have a string "scbdemo2016-10-21:getlastweekReadBooks4795".
How to find out the above string has date in it and to validate the date is current day date.

Comment: Is 4795 always there in your string.

Comment: Yes it may contain like tat.. but there will be only one date like "2016-10-21"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easily done with regular expressions:

```
$isToday = stringDateToday("scbdemo2016-10-21:getlastweekReadBooks4795");

function stringDateToday($string) {
    $reg = "/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/";

    $date = new DateTime();

    preg_match($reg, $string, $matches);

    if (isset($matches[0])) {
        return $matches[0] == $date->format("Y-m-d");
    }

    return false;
}
```

`stringDateToday()` will return `true` if the date in the string is today. The date can be anywhere in the string.

**EDIT:**

As suggested in the comments, you may want to change `new DateTime()` to `new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'))` to specify timezone.

Comment: Just be wary of different time zones.  It may be better to be explicit: `new DateTime('now',  new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));` But that depends on what the OP wants to match and where.

Comment: @Progrock Yes. Of course, this is assuming the dates match the server time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code, but it only works with string that has : character, anyways

```
function checkdata($date, $format)
{
    $format=strstr(preg_replace("/[a-zA-Z]+/", '',$format),":",true);
   // date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
    if($d && $d->format($format) === $date) {

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

$data="scbdemo2016-10-21:getlastweekReadBooks4795";

if(checkdata($data,'Y-m-d'))
echo "Yes";
else
echo "NO";
```

Comment: Side effect here of setting the timezone to UTC, may not be wanted.